# How to add instance to array its sorted for some words

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble with my code.
I want to sort by some words from instance its in array, and resubstitute into  new array.
I made little program to do this.
But Somehow not working. only empty i can see.

-program
--data.php

-index.php

```
<?php

class Hoge {
  private $name;
  private $genre;

  public function __contstruct($name, $genre) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->genre = $genre;
  }

  public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }


  public function getGenre() {
    return $this->genre;
  }

  public static function sortGenre($ary, $what) {
    $arrays = [];
    foreach($ary as $a){
        if ($a->getGenre() == "web") {
            $arrays[] = $a;
        }
    }

    return $arrays;
  }
}


$web1 = new Hoge ('name1','web');
$web2 = new Hoge ('name2','web');
$web3 = new Hoge ('name3','movie');
$web4 = new Hoge ('name4','out');
$web5 = new Hoge ('name5','web');
$web6 = new Hoge ('name6','some');
$web7 = new Hoge ('name7','yammy');

$ary = array($web1,$web2,$web3,$web4,$web5,$web6,$web7);

$webs = Hoge::sortGenre($ary,'web');
```

in index.php

```
<?php foreach ($webs as $web): ?>
<p><?php echo $web->getName() ?></p>
<p><?php echo $web->getGenre() ?></p>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

This comes result with

```
nothing shows
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's your target output?

Comment: `__contstruct` != `__construct` (use the last one). So voting to close as off-topic, because it's a typo!

Comment: target is on website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function __contstruct
```

Typo here, should be

```
public function __construct
```